# Real time visualization of parametric plots

Tags: plotting

I wish to see the following curve develop in real time.

```
f = {Cos[s/Sqrt[2]], -Sin[s/Sqrt[2]], s/Sqrt[2]}

ParametricPlot3D[f,{s,-2Pi,2Pi}]
```

I tried to get manipulate involved with the idea of using the domain parameter s as the manipulate parameter and automate it that way but it wont work. Would just like to see how the curve grows with increasing arclength as s goes from -2pi to 2pi.

Trying

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[f, {s, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {TraditionalForm[x], TraditionalForm[y], 
    TraditionalForm[z]}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], {s, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: try `f = {Cos[s/Sqrt[2]], -Sin[s/Sqrt[2]], s/Sqrt[2]};
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[f, {s, -z, z}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}],
 {{z, .1, "extent"}, .1, 2 Pi, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]` and click on the play arrow in the control for "extent" to see the animation

Comment: Ugh, I see, thx

Comment: Perhaps `Dynamic@With[{j = Clock[{-2 Pi, 2 Pi, 4 Pi/200}, 4]}, ParametricPlot3D[f, {s, -2 Pi, j}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}}]]`  with your choice of `Clock` arguments?